# Livewire search does not rerender the results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to implement livewire to the project. I am just a beginner, I found some basic examples about livewire search, on the web. Everything works perfectly but the page is not rerendering, every time I want to see the results, I have to change the page from paginator which is the bottom of the page. Otherwise, do not rerender the page. I saw some solutions like the page must be in one parent element and every row has to have a key id etc. I applied everything that I saw on the web, but it does not rerender the results after I write down sth into the input field.

Livewire Blade file,

```
<div>
<div class="col-md-9">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Kategorilerde ara..." wire:model="search" class="form-control bg-white" />

    <br>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover" style="overflow: hidden">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>İsim</th>
                    <th>Açıklama</th>
                    <th>Ürün Sayısı</th>
                    <th>Eylem</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <tr wire:key="category-{{ $category->category_id }}">
                    <td>{{$category->category_id}}</td>
                    <td><b>{{$category->category_name}}</b></td>
                    <td>{{$category->category_description}}</td>
                    <td>{{$category->count_products}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="row justify-content-left">
                            <div class="col-3">

                                <a href="{{route("admin.kategori_duzenle", $category->category_id)}}"
                                    class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                                        fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pen" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                        <path
                                            d="m13.498.795.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001zm-.644.766a.5.5 0 0 0-.707 0L1.95 11.756l-.764 3.057 3.057-.764L14.44 3.854a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-1.585-1.585z" />
                                    </svg>

                                </a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">

                                @if($category->count_products==0)
                                <form action="{{route("admin.kategori_sil.post")}}" method="POST">
                                    @csrf
                                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$category->category_id}}" name="category_id">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                                            fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                            <path
                                                d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z">
                                            </path>
                                            <path
                                                d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z">
                                            </path>
                                        </svg>

                                    </button>

                                </form>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    {{$categories->links()}}
</div>
```

Component file:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Category;
use Livewire\WithPagination;


class Searchcategory extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
    protected $listeners = ['refreshPage' => '$refresh'];


    public $search;

    public function mount(){
        
        $this->search = "";
        
    }

    public function render()
    {

      $categories = Category::where('category_name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->paginate(20);
        return view('livewire.searchcategory',[
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);

    }


    public function refreshPage()
    {
        //can verify here that the event successfully emitted to this component. No refresh happens though.
        $this->render();
    }
}
```

Main blade file :

```
<head>
    <title>Kategoriler -</title>
    @include('admin.layouts.head')
    @livewireStyles
</head>

<body>
    <div class="screen-overlay"></div>
    @include('admin.layouts.left')

    <main class="main-wrap">
        @include('admin.layouts.top')
        <section class="content-main">

            <div class="content-header">
                <div>
                    <h2 class="content-title card-title">@if(isset($get_category))

                        Kategori Düzenle
                        @else
                        Kategoriler
                        @endif
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @if(isset($get_category))

                            <form method="POST" action="{{route("admin.kategori_duzenle.post")}}">
                                @csrf
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{$get_category[0]->category_id}}" name="category_id">
                                <div class="mb-4">
                                    <label for="product_name" class="form-label">İsim</label>
                                    <input type="text" required placeholder="Buraya yazın"
                                        value="{{$get_category[0]->category_name}}" name="category_name"
                                        class="form-control" id="category_name" />

                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-4">
                                    <label class="form-label">Üst Kategori</label>


                                    <select class="form-select" name="category_parent">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        @foreach ($categories as $category)

                                        <option value="{{$category->category_id}}" @if($get_category[0]->
                                            category_parent==$category->category_id)

                                            {{"selected='selected'"}}
                                            @endif>{{$category->category_name}}

                                        </option>
                                        @endforeach

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-4">
                                    <label class="form-label">Açıklamalar</label>
                                    <textarea name="category_description" required placeholder="Buraya yazın"
                                        class="form-control">{{$get_category[0]->category_description}}</textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-grid">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary text-center" type="submit" name="">Kategori
                                        Düzenle</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            @else
                            <form method="POST" action="{{route("admin.kategori_ekle.post")}}">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="mb-4">
                                    <label for="product_name" class="form-label">İsim</label>
                                    <input type="text" required placeholder="Buraya yazın" value="" name="category_name"
                                        class="form-control" id="category_name" />

                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-4">
                                    <label class="form-label">Üst Kategori</label>


                                    <select class="form-select" name="category_parent">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        @foreach ($categories as $category)

                                        <option value="{{$category->category_id}}">{{$category->category_name}}
                                        </option>
                                        @endforeach

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-4">
                                    <label class="form-label">Açıklamalar</label>
                                    <textarea name="category_description" required placeholder="Buraya yazın"
                                        class="form-control"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="d-grid">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary text-center" type="submit" name="">Kategori
                                        Ekle</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            @endif

                        </div>
                        @if(session('msg'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{session('msg')}} </div>
                        @endif

                        @error('msg')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{$message}}</div>

                        @enderror

                        @livewire('searchcategory')


                        <!-- .col// -->
                    </div>
             


        </section>

        @include('admin.layouts.footer');
        @livewireScripts

        <!-- content-main end// -->
</body>

</html>
```

Also, I realized that livewire update function works only page is changed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. It was because of lack of ".lazy". I modify the `wire:model="search"` with `wire:model.lazy="search"`. It works well.

Comment: You're a STAR! 

Making my first attempts with Livewire and had the same issue. Nice I didn't have to go in circles for more than 20 min on this one  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Author might already solved the problem. The answer may be `wire::model.live="your_parameter"` according to
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/wire-model#live-updating

Happy Coding

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you're facing an issue where Livewire doesn't automatically re-render the page when you enter text into the search input field. To resolve this issue, you should make sure you follow these steps:

1. **Livewire Component Structure**: Ensure that your Livewire component structure is set up correctly. It looks like you've done this part correctly.
2. **Livewire Model Binding**: You've correctly used `wire:model` on your input field, which should update the `search` property in your Livewire component as you type.
3. **Livewire Re-render**: Livewire should automatically re-render the component when the `search` property changes. However, you're not seeing this behavior. To force a re-render, you can use `$this->search` directly in your Blade file to trigger a refresh.

   ```html
   <input type="text" placeholder="Kategorilerde ara..." wire:model="search" class="form-control bg-white" />

   <!-- Add this button to manually refresh the Livewire component -->
   <button wire:click="$refresh">Refresh</button>
   ```

   When you click the "Refresh" button, it will trigger a Livewire refresh, and the component should re-render with the updated search results.
4. **Pagination**: You mentioned that Livewire's update function works when you change the page. This behavior is expected because Livewire handles pagination automatically. If you want to re-render the component when the search term changes without changing the page, you can use the `$refresh` method as shown above.
5. **Check for JavaScript Errors**: Ensure there are no JavaScript errors in your browser's console that might be preventing Livewire from working correctly.
6. **Livewire Version**: Make sure you are using a compatible version of Livewire with your Laravel application.

If you've followed these steps and are still facing issues, consider checking your browser's console for any Livewire-related errors or potential conflicts with other JavaScript libraries. Additionally, updating to the latest version of Livewire and Laravel might help if you're using older versions.

Comment: button works perfectly but i think problem is with wire.model . Every structure in livewire works well but not wire.model . I do not know why. It makes me crazy for 2 days.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy